# Divide non normal distribution into classes

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

[image]

How can I statistically divide such skewed data into classes (Low, medium and high) as shown in the figure.
Any rule like "68–95–99.7 rule" for non-normal data?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Doesn't this simply involve the *binning* of your counts into a histogram? Binning is dealt with in nearly every introductory text on statistics.

Comment: Without knowing why you want to divide the variable, it's impossible to give good advice. However, for most purposes, dividing the data is a mistake and you should not do it at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to divide it just to describe your data, there are a number of ways you can do it. It all comes down to choosing "cuts". Some stuff to help you think about it:

- Sort and plot your data.
- Aggregate you data (count) by the frequency of the event, compute percentages and accumulate.

** A note of caution: if you want to divide your data just to better describe it, that is fine. Go ahead. But it is generally not a good idea to bin data for analytics purposes. See [this](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/dividingcontinuousintocategories.html).